# Haskell programming to insert a node to the graph

Tags: haskell, computer-science

I'm trying to insert a node to a graph. I already have a function to find the maximum nodeID so the new nodeID is 1 greater than it but I'm having trouble getting the output as a graph.

```
newID :: Maybe NodeID -> NodeID
newID Nothing = 1
newID (Just x) = x+1

insertNode :: a -> Graph a -> Graph a
insertNode v (Graph node_list)=
  let newNode=Node(newID(maxNodeID (Graph node_list))) v
  in (node_list): [[(newNode,[])]]
```

Description for the graph is:

```
newtype Graph a = Graph [(Node a,[NodeID])]
  deriving (Show,Eq)

type NodeID = Int

data Node a = Node { getNodeID  :: NodeID,
                     getNodeVal :: a }
  deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)

nodeA,nodeB,nodeC :: Node Char
nodeA = Node 0 'A'
nodeB = Node 1 'B'
nodeC = Node 2 'C'

exGraph :: Graph Char
exGraph = Graph [(nodeA,[1,2])
                ,(nodeB,[])
                ,(nodeC,[1,2])]
```

I've been stuck for this for 2 hours now. I just want to insert the new node at the end of the graph.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, the only things you have to change are:

- Use `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` instead of `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`. The `:` operator is for inserting things at the front, for adding to the end of a list the simplest way is to use the form `xs ++ [x]`.
- Wrap the result in a `Graph` constructor.

So a working version is:

```
insertNode :: a -> Graph a -> Graph a
insertNode v (Graph node_list)=
  let newNode=Node(newID(maxNodeID (Graph node_list))) v
  in Graph (node_list ++ [(newNode,[])])
```

Comment: For efficiency, one should probably switch the order around (maybe, depending on context). In that case, it would be `(newNode, []) : node_list`.